# Conditional probability given numerous events

Tags: probability

Let's say I have an event $Y$ and events $X_i$ such that I am able to compute compute $P(Y | X_i)$ for each $X_i$ individually.

Now how can I compute $P(Y|\bigcup_i^n X_i)$ and $P(Y|\bigcap_i^n X_i)$ from it?

Answer (score 2):

Knowing $P(Y \mid X_i)$ for each $X_i$ is insufficient knowledge to compute $P(Y \mid \cup_{i=1}^n X_i)$ or $P(Y \mid \cap_{i=1}^n X_i)$. You would need some knowledge on how the $X_i$ interact (e.g. independence or mutual exclusivity).

For example, consider tossing two independent fair coins. Let $A$ be the event the first coin comes up heads. Let $B$ be the event the second coin comes up heads. Let $Y$ be the probability there is exactly one tails. Let $P(Y \mid A) = P(Y \mid B) = \frac{1}{2}$.

If we take $X_1 = X_2 = A$ then $P(Y \mid X_1 \cup X_2) = P(Y \mid X_1 \cap X_2) = P(Y \mid A) = \frac{1}{2}$. However if we take $X_1 = A$ and $X_2 = B$, which gives the same values of $P(Y \mid X_i)$, then $P(Y \mid X_1 \cup X_2) = \frac{2}{3}$ and $P(Y \mid X_1 \cap X_2) = 0$.